# Can I influence the bone envelopes?

Tags: rigging, bones, armature

I was hoping I could get some help here.
Is there any way to influence the bone envelopes?

My Problem:
I have an Armature and the Armature is set in stone and can't be changed.
I have also an Avatar that is rigged to this Armature.

Now, I want to make a cloth item for said avatar. The problem is, automatic weights are too inaccurate for the given armature. And the bone envelopes are too big to help here. I found the settings for the envelopes but it seems they only influence them as a whole.
E.G. if I shrink the "distance" it shrinks the influence as a whole.

Maybe someone has an idea how to influence the distance in an x or y axis only ?
Pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify the bone envelope's scale at individual axis, separately.

A bone's envelope distance is stored as a single attribute [`envelope_distance`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Bone.html#bpy.types.Bone.envelope_distance), without any way to modify it for a single axis. This is unlike b-bone scale which is stored separately in [`bbone_x`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Bone.html#bpy.types.Bone.bbone_x) and [`bbone_z`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Bone.html#bpy.types.Bone.bbone_z), thus can be scaled separately.

Your only choice here is through weight painting, already elaborated in the other answers posted before mine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the vertices that are affected by adjusting their weights in weight paint mode. Select a bone, select the object (avatar) and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> to go into weight paint mode (or select it from the mode menu). You'll have the ability to paint on your mesh now. Red means full weight and blue means no weight.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.I know about the weight paint mode.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using the weight paint to better customize the influence your armature has on the clothing objects for your character. Deforming via envelopes can be a quick solution for simple objects, but for full control you will need to become more acquainted with Weight Painting.

Weight Painting will allow you to customize how your object responds to the influence of your armature.

Here is a pretty good explanation on Weight Painting:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBS1qy4jzTg

Good luck.